# How can I track mouse position every 500 milliseconds for 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, events

I want to capture the mouse pointer position after every 500 milliseconds for 10 secs lets suppose. Can someone please help?!

I tried using 'mousemove' event but couldn't move any further with this approach. Here's the code, hope this helps you. The removeEventListner on mousemove is not working correctly.

```js
 var loadTime;
 var loadDate;
 var clickTime;
 var mousePositions = [];
 var closeCapture = false;
 var isTimerON = false;
 var timer_div = document.getElementById('timer-section');
 var x , y;
 function mouseUpdate(e) {
  if (isTimerON) {
   x = e.pageX;
   y = e.pageY;

  // if the timer is ON and position capturing is OPEN then push
  //  the last pointer position to the array
   if (!closeCapture){
    var mouseUpdate = setInterval(function () {
     mousePositions.push({
      pos_x : x,
      pos_y : y
     });
     
    }, 500);
   }
  }
  else{
   document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseUpdate);
  }
 }

 function setTimer (time) {

  var x = time;
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseUpdate);

  if (isTimerON) {
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (x >= 0){
     timer_div.innerHTML = x;
     console.log(x);

     x--;
    } 
    else {
     //console.log(mousePositions);
     isTimerON = false;
     closeCapture = true;
     clearInterval(timer);
     console.log("timer off capture closed");
     
    }
   
   },1000);
  }
 }

 function makeTime(x) {
  return  x.getHours() + " : " + x.getMinutes() + " : " + x.getSeconds();
 }

 function tii() {
  isTimerON = true;
  setTimer(10);
  document.removeEventListener('click', tii);
 }

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  loadCDate = new Date();
  loadTime = makeTime(loadCDate); 
  console.log(loadTime);  
  document.addEventListener('click', tii);
 });
```

```html
<div id="timer-section"></div>
```

Comment: What was wrong with mousemove events? If no further event is sent then you know that no movement has been made.

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] of what you've tried, otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest capturing `mousemove` events for the duration of your time limit (in this example I've set `limit` to 10 seconds). The `throttle` variable ensures you only capture once per that many milliseconds (in this example 500ms).

You can use the x/y co-ordinates of the mousemove event to get the current position of the mouse.

```
const limit = 10000
const throttle = 500
const start = (new Date).getTime()

let last = (new Date).getTime()

const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    const now = (new Date).getTime()
    if ((now - start) > limit) {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
        return
    }

    if ((now - last) < throttle) {
        return
    }

    last = now

    // do whatever you want to do within your time limit here
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#throttle. the throttle function will make you capture event in a setup freq. If you code is handle every callback of mouse event. you program will be freeze.